# Stop Sweave code chunks in RMarkdown from displaying execution output whilst still displaying the code

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I'm writing a publication manuscript for a new R package. The author guidelines expect a self-contained Sweave (Latex+R) project with self-contained executable code within R code chunks in the Sweave document. This allows for seamless reviewing. Recommendations are to use RStudio.

All is going well. However, some of my packaged R code prints to the terminal intermediate steps; notably in the parts that setup and execute parallel code. In terms of use, this is great. However, the intermediate output is bulking out the code chunks in the compiled PDF. Not great for a scientific manuscript with a limited page count (fine elsewhere, e.g., Github wiki etc).

I'm using the code chunk options:

```
<<eval=T, echo=T>>=
#R code to execute AND to display code here. 
#But this print all internal R print() statements to the pdf document.
@
```

Is there a Sweave code chunk option (not a global option, as for some code chunks the current behaviour is fine) that executes and displays the code itself but halts the printing of any internal print statements in my R package?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to my own question I figured this out through a process of elimination; I could have continued scrolling through online blogs and tutorial but I'm very much pressed for time.

To suppress the output of a calculation in an R code chunk whilst displaying the R code in the compiled pdf:

```
<<eval=T, echo=T,results=hide>>=
```

eval=T -- evaluate the code

echo=T -- spits the code into the pdf (and the code output)

results=hide -- overrides echo=T to prevent the code's output whilst maintaining the code display.